# Mui Cards Hover Effect won't be disappear in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

```
.MuiCard-root.card:hover{
    background-color: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}[enter image description here][1]
```

I'm trying to remove the default background effect on Mui cards on hover in react.js.I tried all its classes by inspect it but wont be work.please guid me about it, that how to disable the hover effect of MUI cards
Also same questions about MUI buttons components that how i also disable the background effect on buttons